# Dyanmically create gridview in code behind with template field

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I need to create gridviews dynamically, of particular design(only 4 columns), first column has a checkbox, and the rest are boundfields, how can i create this, and bind the dynamically created gridview, is it possible to bind checkbox also(i have a bool column for this).

Later i need to check and uncheck rows, and on button click will i be able to access this dynamically created gridview to find checked and unchecked rows.

EDIT:
i have a data set with many(unknown no of) datatables having 4 columns,i need to Provide a UI for the user to change Data with in this DS.

Comment: First: why do you need to create it dynamically. Can you share some background informations of your requirement? In most cases there's a simpler approach than to create dynamical controls.

Comment: i have a data set with many(unknown no of) datatables having 4 columns,i need to Provide a UI for the user to change Data with in this DS.

Comment: What have you tried? I would suggest to encapsulate the `GridView` and the logic into a `WebUserControl` which you can then create dynamically(`LoadControl`). That'll simplify all.

Comment: foreach (DataTable dtable in dset.Tables)
            {
                grd = new GridView();
                grd.Caption = dtable.TableName;

                TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
                grd.Columns.Add(tf);

                BoundField bf = new BoundField();
                grd.Columns.Add(bf);
                pnl.controls.add(grd);
            }